# Select specific rows from Multiple Excel workbooks, Each containing multiple worksheets. Then Writing the filtered rows to CSV or .xlsx

Tags: c#, excel

Initial format

[image: Initial format]

I am needing to write a program using C#. It is my first project and could use some assistance please!!!
 I have Multiple Workbooks which can have hundreds of sheets. Each Sheet for a Store within the specified region.

I am needing to select specific rows from each sheet using a ProductCode. 
Note Sheets have merged and wrapped cells.

I am then required to write the data to a new CSV or MSExcel.xlsx 
in Order to import  into SQL Server.

desired result

[image: desired result]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. you should provide code from your attempt., you are more likely to get a good answer if your provide some relevant code (it doesn't have to work)

Comment: Thank for the Feedback Kevin I will be sure to add it onto the question